# The communication between kernel helper thread and Kernel level code

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I'm studying Linux kernel and I'm wondering if I can do like below assuming a helper kernel thread already created.

A code was inserted in a sys_call(ex. in sys_execv()).
I would make the code in the sys_call send a signal to the kernel thread, and the code "shall wait or stop" until receive a completion event from the helper thread.

How the code can do this?
Thank you for your help in advance.

//DAUM

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make kernel thread communication?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034249/how-can-i-make-kernel-thread-communication)

Answer (score 0):

Signals are meant for user space processes. Although it is possible to allow certain signals (like SIGKILL) to a kernel thread but we cannot have signal handlers in kernel threads. So the signal based approach will not work.

It is better to explore other approaches based on work queues to achieve the same thing.